# Button causing crash

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a table view and i put a ToolBar button so when button is clicked open a Map View.
When I click the button my application crash, so I tried this:

```
 MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];

 // NSArray *categories = nil;
    switch ([indexPath row]){
     case 0:
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];  
       ....
```

And when I tap a corresponding cell it open new view and my mapView is working like a charm
But when I put same in the Button action method my application crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you implemented the action method?

Comment: - (void) pressButton1:(id)sender{
    MapViewController *mvc = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];}
// The crash Log:
buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5853470
2011-06-14 15:11:14.374 TattooShops[16644:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MonteraController buttonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5853470'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you pass the wrong selector when you connect the button to the action.

If you have created the button programattically.

1. Don't forget to add it to the view.
2. The selector should look something like this: `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressButton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Note the **:** in pressButton1: